# Help diagnosing rattling sound table saw

Tags: table-saw

My table saw (Elektra Beckum [PKF255](https://www.free-instruction-manuals.com/pdf/p4777392.pdf) ) makes a strange metallic sounding rattling noise and I can't seem to figure out where it is coming from.

Here's the sound with the new freud blade:
https://youtu.be/oEkEZrK2oWI

And here's the (acceptable) sound with the original blade:
https://youtu.be/TeQlYzQDWLA

Here's the sound without blade:
https://youtube.com/shorts/wmH_PUwVGUc

The sound only really occurs with the thicker new blade, which has alternating top bevels (ATB). With the original blade it only occurs for a brief moment when the saw gets up to speed.

The sound does not occur when the motor is stopped.

There is no contact between blade and table as far as I can see or hear upon manually rotating the blade. I have increased the gap between the blade and the table top to be sure.

Without the blade on there's a slight noise from a loose washer, but I've check this and that washer is supposed to be loose to allow for the tilting motor.

What could I do to further diagnose this problem?

**Update**
Something's definitely still loose inside the motor but I can't access it from the slot. Would it be a good idea to remove the motor using the bolts shown on this picture? https://i.postimg.cc/1tHKtcTd/IMG-0817.jpg

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange and congrats on a well-asked Question. My read on this could well be wrong so one of the TS guys will hopefully be along soon to weigh in on this. But FWIW the first thing I'd do is secure any and all lose fasteners. As the saw started up with the Freud blade fitted my eye was immediately drawn to the bolt at left dancing around in the slot. When the original spins up to speed that bolt moves differently.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked the (riving knife) bolt but that's not the culprit. I have checked everything inside the table I can check without disassembling everything

Comment: OK, good to rule that out.

Comment: Something's definitely still loose inside the motor but I can't access it from the slot. Would it be a good idea to remove the motor using the bolts shown on this picture? https://i.postimg.cc/1tHKtcTd/IMG-0817.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry you haven't received more input on this (yet?) but it is very slow here these days unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried another good blade? Personal anecdote: for way-too-long, my jobsite tablesaw (Bosch 4000) would randomly flutter and widen the kerf. I changed all the bearings; I tightened everything. Never crossed my mind that my really high end blade could be at fault. Change blade, problem gone. Lesson learned.

Comment: Check that the drive belt tension is correct and if the motor has grease fittings try adding grease to the bearings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a tiny bit of play around the arbor. The Freud blade arbor hole was not exactly 30mm. Fixed by adding a tiny bit of duct tape.

So, it was indeed the blade. My mistake to fall for that fancy red paint  ;-)

For completeness sake: I also removed the motor, which is the only way to check/adjust belt tension on this machine. Just four bolts holding the motor in place.
Belt was fine. I noticed that there's still a small part vibrating inside of the motor. As it's not affecting the operation of the saw, I decided not to open up the motor.

Comment: Thanks for the self-Answer and I'm glad you found out the problem. This is not the first time that I've heard that arbor holes supposedly a given diameter can be off-spec by enough to cause an issue, even with higher-end brands rather alarmingly.